# Failing to mock @Autowired Object

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4, powermock

I am using Junit4 and Mockito for test cases, in the following code I am trying to mock a autowired object which throws null pointer exception inside the mocking class which means autowired object is not mocking properly

ContentDao.java

```
public class ContentDao {

  @Autowired 
  private ConfigProperties configProperties;

  public void fuction() {
  int batchSize = configProperties.getBatchSize();
}
```

ConfigProperties.java

```
@ConfigurationProperties(ignoreUnknownFields = false, prefix = "cleanup")
public class ConfigProperties {

  private int batchSize;

  public int getBatchSize() {
    return batchSize;
  }
}
```

Trying to mock ConfigProperties.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ContentDaoTest{

   @InjectMocks
   private ContentDao contentDao;

   @Mock
   private ConfigProperties configProperties;

   @Test
   public void functionTest(){
      configProperties = mock(ConfigProperties.class);
      when(configProperties.getBatchSize()).thenReturn(100);
      ContentDao contentDao = new ContentDao();
      contentDao.funtion();
   }
```

funtion is called, but I get NPE in below line. Please help I am stuck here.

```
int batchSize = configProperties.getBatchSize();
```

Comment: Ofcourse you will ge a `NullPointer`... You are destroying the instance with mocked references with the `new ContentDao()`.

Comment: You need to injectMock or set the properties into the ContentDao class. Ops...Ok you have done that. Try moving the @mock ConfigProperties above the @ injectMocks

Comment: Try to declare" private MockMvc mockMvc; " in autowired.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Then should I be deleting 'new ContentDao()' and call the function from Injected 'contentDao'?

Comment: You have a lot of annotations and the first thing you do is make those useless. So yes remove the `ne ContentDao()`. as well as the `mock(ConfigProperties.class)`. What do you think the `@Mock` annotation combined with the `MockitoJUnitRunner` does? Work with the framework you use not against/around it.

Comment: @M.Deinum: when I remove, function is not even being called. I checked it by writing sysout statement.

Comment: What do you think should call `function`? You are writing a test call it from the test...

Comment: remove this two lines`configProperties = mock(ConfigProperties.class);`  `ContentDao contentDao = new ContentDao();`

Comment: @M.Deinum: Then how do i call with initializing contentDao?

Comment: What do you think `@InjectMocks` does... That will give you an instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thanks for clear explanation. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you set `@Mock` for configProperties, you should not mock again `configProperties = mock(ConfigProperties.class);`
In the same idea, as you set `@InjectMocks` for contentDao, you should not instantiate a new contentDao.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ContentDaoTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ContentDao contentDao;

    @Mock
    private ConfigProperties configProperties;

    @Test
    public void functionTest() {
        Mockito.when(configProperties.getBatchSize()).thenReturn(100);
        Assertions.assertThat(contentDao.getBatchSize()).isEqualTo(100);
    }
}
```